# Electron: Button and drag’n’drop events don’t work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I have an app made with Electron, and works perfectly in my old notebook with Win7.

Now I cloned the code with git in my new win10 notebook, installed node.js and made “npm install”.
When I try to execute it by “npm start” the app opens, but nothing works, neither the button, and neither the drag’n’drop area that exists in my app.

One curious thing is that when I execute the executable, made in the old notebook, all the functionalities work perfectly. But I need to change somethings in the code now, so it isn’t a solution for me.

Someone could help me? Maybe is this a installation problem? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
 When I cloned the code in a new notebook, it downloaded Electron version 5.0.0 with npm, and the version that works with my app is 4.1.0. 
 So I fixed the Electron version in package.json and works fine.

Comment: I'm going to do it, but stackoverflow just allow me in some hours.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing based on your question that you created a frameless window, i.e., you set `frame` to `false` in BrowserWindow's options, something like this:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, frame: false })
win.show()
```

If you did so then you must have set draggable region like this:

```
.titlebar {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

Now, for your buttons to work inside the draggable region you need to set your buttons as non-draggable like this:

```
button {
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you face any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The code itself works, I have a button in a region of the screen and it works, and also the dragndrop region that is in another region of the screen.

The problem is that I made a new installation in a new computer, and I don't know if I forget something in the installation process, or if to work in windows 10 there is a difference between WIn7. And if I need to add something in PATH.

Comment: Would you zip the code and provide me a link to it? I can debug the code for you! Most probably it's not a problem with the installation as the app starts on Windows 10. It may be a problem with the code.